# Multiple Examples for same Target

Tags: regression, machine-learning, modeling, feature-selection, dataset

I'm looking to train a regression on this dataset:

$$
D : (f_{1}, y_{1}),(f_{i}, y_{i}), …, (f_{n}, y_n)
$$

Where $y$ is an range of integers from $\{1,2...,n\}$ i.e. not continuous like in the traditional regression case. Given that the response is in some sense discrete, it can have many examples for a given $y_i$.

How can I generalize this problem?